# ApolloClient client's Type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, apollo

I have a function where I pass the client as a parameter and delete the token from my app etc:

```
  const logOut = async (client: ApolloClient<unknown>) => {...};
```

```
return (
    <ApolloConsumer>
      {(client: ApolloClient<unknown>) => (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaViewContainer}>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button
                  onPress={() => logOut(client)}
                  style={styles.button}
                />
              </View>
             </SafeAreaView>
      )}
    </ApolloConsumer>
  );
};
```

Right now I am using `unknown`for the ApolloClient type and it works. But what should I actually be using here?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at `@apollo/client/react/context/ApolloConsumer.d.ts`, you can see that the type of the client is `ApolloClient<object>` (in older react-apollo the type was `ApolloClient<any>`)

```
import React from "react";
import { ApolloClient } from "../../core";
export interface ApolloConsumerProps {
  children: (client: ApolloClient<object>) => React.ReactChild | null;
}
export declare const ApolloConsumer: React.FC<ApolloConsumerProps>;
//# sourceMappingURL=ApolloConsumer.d.ts.map
```

I would **not** specify the `client`'s type explicitly. TypeScript is smart enough
to infer it automatically.

If you still want to write a stricter type, the generic in ApolloClient is `TCacheShape`, and it depends on the cache you use with apollo.

For example, you are using `InMemoryCache`, the generic type is `NormalizedCacheObject`

```
export interface NormalizedCacheObject {
  [dataId: string]: StoreObject | undefined;
}

export interface StoreObject {
  __typename?: string;
  [storeFieldName: string]: StoreValue;
}
```